# :before pseudo-element on container has a white border

Tags: html, css, lines, element, diagonal

I'm using the :before and :after pseudo-elements to create diagonal lines a container.

What happens is that those pseudo-elements seem to have a white bottom border, which I cannot explain.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
#sobre:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    height: 6em;

    background: inherit;

    content: '';

    transform: skewY(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-2deg);

    transform-origin: -100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: -100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: -100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: -100%;
}
```

The code for :after is the same, just with a different transform-origin and a z-index: 1 for it to overlap the next container.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Is it possible that there are :after and :before defined somewhere else in css? Try to add border: none to #sobre:before

Comment: Likely to be anti-aliasing or sub-pixel rendering.

Comment: @Kantoci I have tried to add that and it didn't work. If I add, for example, border: 1px solid black, it does add a black border around the element but maintains that white line you see on the image.

Comment: @Paulie_D It happens only on Chrome. On Opera and Firefox, it displays a seemless container.

Comment: Then the requested [mcve] would be optimal..but Chrome does have rendering difference to other browsers,

Comment: Try this: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Comment: @Kantoci That did the trick, thanks a lot! 
If you would post that as as response I could accept the answer :)

Comment: great, thank you  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common antialiasing issue in Chrome caused by CSS transforms, add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your `:after` and `:before` elements.

Comment: This answer would have been much more awesome if you had included some authoritative sources.